# How to replace a bamboo job with its spec equivalent?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

If you have an existing bamboo job configured through the bamboo browser UI and export that configuration through its corresponding `Bamboo Java Specs` to a java file how do you then setup the existing bamboo plan or create a new one to define all its build logic using that exported spec?

Answer (score 1):

When you export plan configuration to Java specs you need to create new repository at Bitbucket Server. Create bamboo-specs folder at root of that repo.
Run command

```
mvn archetype:generate -B \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.atlassian.bamboo -DarchetypeArtifactId=bamboo-specs-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.3 \
    -DgroupId=com.atlassian.bamboo -DartifactId=bamboo-specs -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackage=tutorial -Dtemplate=minimal
```

Then replace generated Plan.java with code you've got for your plan from Bamboo UI.
Commit all changes to repository and then follow steps at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-java-specs-894743911.html to configure repository at Bamboo side